# ASPxDateEdit conditional formatting

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I have an ASPxDateEdit control and I want it to display the date in red if it's in the past.

Edit:  I should note that I do not want to validate the date.  I just simply want it to display red.

Comment: Why don't you contact DevExpress support directly?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the **ASPxDateEdit.CalendarDayCellPrepared** event to implement the required conditional formatting.

Take a look at the [Custom Day Rendering](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxEditorsDemos/ASPxCalendar/DayRender.aspx) demo. It illustrates how to deal with this approach using the ASPxCalendar (the same technique can be applied using the ASPxDateEdit).

Answer (score 0):

This is the control code on the aspx page

```
<dx:ASPxDateEdit ID="deControl"  ClientInstanceName="deControl" runat="server"      
OnCalendarDayCellPrepared="deControl_CellPrepared">
</dx:ASPxDateEdit>
```

This is the code-behind event

```
protected void deControl_CellPrepared(object sender, 
CalendarDayCellPreparedEventArgs e)
{
    if (DateTime.Compare(e.Date, DateTime.Now)<0)
    {
        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
}
```